# aapt tool failed:ERROR: input directory '--auto-add-overlay' does not exist air native exntesion

Tags: android, ane

i have problem when make ane google analytics 
Errors: aapt tool failed:ERROR: input directory '--auto-add-overlay' does not exist
Who can help me ,pls

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved.When using 3rd-party jars,you should specify  resources in aapt platform-option file.Adobe explained this [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html).
Note that in the following code. `packagedResource` cannot ignored.

```
`<packagedDependencies> 
    <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency> 
    <packagedDependency>google-play-services.jar</packagedDependency> 
</packagedDependencies> 
<packagedResources> 
  <packagedResource> 
        <packageName>com.myane.sampleasextension</packageName> 
        <folderName>ane-res</folderName> 
    </packagedResource> 
    <packagedResource> 
        <packageName>com.google.android.gms</packageName> 
        <folderName>google-play-services-res</folderName> 
    </packagedResource> 
</packagedResources>`
```